# error C2600: what does this means?

Tags: c++, class, mobile, constructor, compiler-errors

I am starting to program in c++ and im getting an error i cant resolve or understand

error C2600: 'kingMobile::KingChatFilter::KingChatFilter' : cannot define a compiler-generated special member function (must be declared in the class first)

And here is the code:

```
#include "buraco/game/board/model/KingChatFilter.h"
#include "buraco\game/board/model\GamePlayController.h"
#include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp"
#include "s3e.h"
#include "buraco\Player.h"
namespace kingMobile {

    KingChatFilter::KingChatFilter() {
        //this->gamePlayController = gamePlayController;

    }

    string KingChatFilter::filter(string msg){

        if(msg == "anus"){
            return "amigao";
        }
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Here i have my .h file

```
#include "buraco\game/board/model\CardGroup.h"
#include "boost/function.hpp"
#include "oxygine-framework.h"

namespace kingMobile {

    class KingChatFilter : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<KingChatFilter> {
        public:

            string filter(string msg);

        private:

    };

    typedef boost::shared_ptr<KingChatFilter> spKingChatFilter;
}
```

Comment: You didn't declare the constructor.

Comment: (in the class definition in `KingChatFilter.h`)

Comment: There is my KingChatFilter.h ... didnt i declare that there ?

Comment: I'm curious about the `msg == "anus"` part...

Comment: No you did not declare the constructor in the KingChatFilter.h you provided.

Comment: @archie, if the questioner's language is Portugese, then `buraco` is also curious... but none of our business anyway :)

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: Buraco is the name of a game in portuguese and that function will be a filter for messages like if u type "anus" it returns "buddy" or "friend" lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the error mesage means that this constructor (special member function)

```
KingChatFilter()
```

at first must be declared in the class definition. For example

```
class KingChatFilter
{
public:
   KingChatFilter();
//...
};
```

Only after that you may define it outside the class definition.

You may not redefine implicitly declared by the compiler constructors including the default constructor.

In fact I repeated the error message of the compiler::)

> /You/ cannot define a compiler-generated special member function (must
>   be declared in the class first)

Answer (score 2):

Even if you have defined the implementation of the constructor in your code, you still need to declare the function in the definition of the class. 
In this case, you would need to add KingChatFilter(); in the public part of your class (in the .h)